# How to loop index after I using input function?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm writing a program when the user enter 'apple' at first time, it will print the day 0 and the first element in list. when the user enter 'apple' at second time, it will print the day 1 and the second element. And I want to repeat these for 30 times for 30 days.

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks

my code:

```
list_1=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
index = 6
a = 0
i = 0
while True:
a = input("Enter:")
if a == "apple":
    if i < 31:
        index = (index + 1) % 7
        d = list_1[index]
        print( "day" ,i, d )
        start = input("Start: ")
        current = input("Current: ")
        i += 1   
        a += 1
```

my output:

```
   Enter:apple
   day 0 a
   Start: 2
   Current: 3

   day 1 b
   Start: 2
   Current: 3

   day 2 c
   Start: 2
   Current: 3
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

Expexted output:

```
   Enter:apple
   day 0 a
   Start: 2
   Current: 3

   Enter:apple
   day 1 b
   Start: 2
   Current: 3
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
   Enter:apple
   day 6 g
   Start: 2
   Current: 3

   Enter:apple
   day 7 a
   Start: 2
   Current: 3
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
   Enter:apple
   day 30 c
   Start: 2
   Current: 3
```

Comment: You are initializing `index`, `a` and `i` inside the loop, so they start from 0 every time. Initialize them before the loop.

Comment: after I putting  index , a and i before the loop, I can not loop the input before the day number.     My new ouput is :                                                                                Enter:apple
day 0 g
Start: 3
Current: 4
day 1 a
Start: 5

Comment: How does the line: `start = input("Start: ")` print a number? It just prints `Start: ` and place for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it produces what you want. You have to move both i and index outside of the loop.

```
list_1=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
i = 0
index = 6
while True:
    a = input("Enter:")
    if a == "apple":
        a = 0
        if i < 31:
            index = (index + 1) % 7
            d = list_1[index]
            print( "day" ,i, d )
            start = input("Start: ")
            current = input("Current: ")
            i = i + 1
            a = a + 1
```

Here's what the loop that you posted is doing

```
while(true) #like saying while true is a true statement or while true==true
    get user input
    if input == 'apple'
        then set a=0, i=0, index=6
        if i < 31 #which it can't be because we just set it to 0
            Do some arithmetic on index #which will always start as 6 because we just assigned it
            ...
            increase i and a by 1 #They will be equal to 1 now
Now go through the loop again
     get input
     if input=='apple'
          set a=0, i=0, and index=6 again
          check i<31 #can't be, we just set it to 0
              do arithmetic on index #which is equal to 6 again because we just set it.
              ...
              increase a and i by 1
And your loop does this over and over
```

But if you first assign i and index outside the loop, then we only set them equal to 0 and 6 once.

Answer (score 1):

As @aryerez has pointed already pointed out, you're initializing the variable 'i' within the loop hence it'll always get reset to zero in each iteration. 
So solution will be keep the initialization line - `i = 0` before the while loop.
 I do not understand why you're incrementing variable 'a' because it is your input variable.